# Extend configuration with custom settings loaded from file

Tags: node.js, json, configuration-files, custom-configuration, node-config

I am trying to extend the configuration for my application with value loaded from a custom configuration file. We are using `node-config` and this is what I am trying to do:

```
// Server entry
const config = require('config')

// Merge setting from our custom configuration
const customConfig = require('../config/custom.json')
config.extendDeep(config, customConfig)
```

The above works, but since we are also using caching for the generated configuration file I will also have to do the above when ever the configuration is reloaded.

I know that I for instance could create a `config/<hostname>.json` which will get merged, but the custom configuration file is generated from another system and I am not able to change the name of the file in this setup.

Is there a better way of adding settings from a custom configuration file using `node-config`?